# Vim doesn't delete underlying lines in Visual Block Mode

Tags: vim

In vim, by pressing **Ctrl+V** you can enter Visual block mode.
When I select multiple lines by moving around with **h,j,k and l**, and press delete using **d or D**, the **text gets deleted, but the underlying lines remain there.**

Which means although the text is gone, the surrounding code is still spaced out a lot.

Is there any way to delete the lines + the text?

Comment: Please paste the `before` and `after` text. It will give a clear picture what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to select *lines* use linewise Visual mode (`V`). If you want to select *characters* use character Visual mode (`v`). If you want to select a rectangular block use blockwise Visual mode (`Ctrl-V`).

Deleting a visual rectangular block *does not* delete the lines. This is the expected behavior. If you want to select lines visually and delete them, use linewise visual mode (`V`), select the lines with `j` and `k` (or down-arrow and up-arrow), then press `d` to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function in an autocmd that before saving a file it removes spaces and empty lines.

```
" Removes trailing whitespace and blank lines leaving 1 blank line between functions.

function! TrimWhitespace()

    " skip these filetypes
    if (&ft=='markdown' || &ft=='help')
        return
    endif
    let l:save = winsaveview()
    " remove whitespace
    %s/\s\+$//e
    " remove blank lines
    %s/\(\s*\n\)\{3,}/\r\r/ge
    call winrestview(l:save)
endfunction

command! TWs call TrimWhitespace()

" this autocmd is called when any of the following files is saved

" edit filetypes as needed.

au BufWritePre *.c,*.sh,*.h,*.vim,*.vimrc,*.txt,*.local,.*rc,.*profile :TWs
```